# C++ Map erases the element but inserts it another time

Tags: c++, dictionary

The following code deletes the Content with the key "text" in the map.

```
void Texts::eliminar(string &text){
    map<string,Content>::iterator it = Cites.find(text);
    if(it==Contents.end()){
        cout << "error" << endl;
    }
    else{
        Contents.erase(it);
    }
}
```

Just afer deleting it, the Content is no longer there. But after some time, and without adding it, there is another Content with the same key but empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `operator[]` on a non-const map will add the key to the map even if a read access is intended.

If you execute

```
std::map<std::string,std::string> myMap;
std::cout << myMap["mykey"];
```

you will end up with an entry in myMap which has a key named "mykey" and an empty value.

Comment: I had to add this even if this question is answered because the answer did not address the real problem. (See comment from oriol20 to the accepted answer)

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry, this is why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 3):

An iterator obtained from `Cites.find(text);` cannot be compared against `Contents.end()`, unless `Cites` and `Contents` name the same object. Therefore, your code has undefined behaviour.